# spring boot actuator health check endpoint with no information in browser in Production server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are using Spring Boot 1.5.2 where We are using Spring Boot starter Actuator,
when we are hitting URL with Health check endpoint we are getting
status= up, but we want blank information(information should not be shown there in browser)(any information will not be available for any public user).

Comment: Actuator Endpoint should be available in via management port and management port should not be open for public

Answer (score 1):

By default, actuator endpoints are exposed on the same port that serves regular HTTP traffic. You can set different level of security for management Endpoints. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) is a details guide about security of management EndPoint.

You can also run your management API in different port and do not make this port open for public. Just use

```
management.port=8085
```

Comment: Can you send some code regarding this, and for localhost what I do pls let me know

Comment: Code for what? I have already provided two solution approach in my answer

Answer (score -1):

We are using Spring Boot 1.5.2 where We are using Spring Boot starter Actuator,
when we are hitting URL with Health check endpoint we are getting
status= up, but we want blank information(information should not be shown there in browser)(any information will not be available for any public user).

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: @M. Deinum please let me know the answer for localhost and production